# Send default POST variable in all Axios requests

Tags: javascript, axios

I need to add the default global variable to all my POST requests using Axios.

I'm able to add the parameter using interceptor like:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.params = config.params || {};
  config.params['timezone_adjust'] = window.timezone_adjust;
  return config;
});
```

But in this case the url looks like "{url}?timezone_adjust=0

However I want to include the timezone_adjust variable on the request data object instead. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a "global" settings to all your `POST` requests you should prefer using `headers` instead of `body` payload

Why? different requests may have different body payload, yet they can share common headers set (it is more common than shared payload)

In that case you can use [Global axios defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults)

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['YOUR-COMMON-HEADER'] = 'HEADER-VALUE';
```

Then you should fetch your headers from `request` object in your backend